# Not sorting right in ascending order when last element is the biggest in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Hi guys i'm new in coding and i've faced a little issue with my sorting the last few days. If i have 3 elements, lets say 1-3-2, sorting works fine, but when i have the biggest number in the end ( 2-1-3) it doesnt work at all. I can't find any solution, i've read tons of questions and materials, but i still cannot find a solution how to make it sort when i have the biggest element in the end. There is the code i hope some of you could find the mistake.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
public class MainClass {

private static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Human> arr){
    arr.forEach(x -> x.printInfo());
}// end 

private static ArrayList<Human> sortComparator(ArrayList<Human> arr){

    Object[] sortedHumans = arr.stream().sorted(new Comparator<Human>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Human h1, Human h2){
            return Float.compare(h1.salary, h2.salary);
        }
    }).toArray();

    ArrayList<Human> sortedArr = new ArrayList<Human>();


    for(int i=0;i<sortedHumans.length;i++){
        sortedArr.add((Human)sortedHumans[i]);
    }


    return sortedArr;
}// end 

private static ArrayList<Human> sortArrayList(ArrayList<Human> arr){
    ArrayList<Human> result = new ArrayList<Human>();

    if(arr.size()>0){
        result.add(arr.get(0));
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
    boolean flag = false;

    for(int i=1;i<arr.size();i++){

        for(int j=0;j<result.size();j++){
            if(arr.get(i).salary < result.get(j).salary){
                result.add(j,arr.get(i));
                flag = true;
                break;
            }// end for j
            else;   
        }//end for j
        if(!flag){
            result.add(arr.get(i)); 
            flag = false;
        }
        else;
    }// end for i 
    return result;  
}// end sort

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Human> myList = new ArrayList<Human>();
    Human h1 = new Human("Ivan","Ivanov", 33, 1000);
    Human h2 = new Human("Petyr","Petrov", 53, 800);
    Human h3 = new Human("Georgi","Georgiev", 23, 1548);

    myList.add(h1);
    myList.add(h2);
    myList.add(h3);
    printArrayList(sortArrayList(myList));
    System.out.println("--------------");
    printArrayList(sortComparator(myList));
}// end main

}// end MainClass
```

There is the output when the last element is the biggest.

```
   Petyr - Petrov - 53 - 800.0
   Ivan - Ivanov - 33 - 1000.0
```

There is the output when the last element is not the biggest,the sorting
works...

```
    Georgi - Georgiev - 23 - 548.0
    Petyr - Petrov - 53 - 800.0
    Ivan - Ivanov - 33 - 1000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your second `sortArrayList` method is that you are not resetting the `flag` variable in the right place, so the `if(!flag)` condition doesn't add the last element to the sorted list if the last element is the biggest.

`flag` should be `false` at the start of each iteration of the inner loop.

Suggested fix :

```
for(int i=1;i<arr.size();i++){
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int j=0;j<result.size();j++){
        if(arr.get(i).salary < result.get(j).salary){
            result.add(j,arr.get(i));
            flag = true;
            break;
        }// end for j 
    }//end for j
    if(!flag){
        result.add(arr.get(i)); 
        flag = false;
    }
}// end for i
```

Comment: What a bummer... I knew that it's going to be something little because everything else looks perfect. My teacher also said that there is something wrong with the flags, but i didn't know that i have to put it into the inner loop. Thank you very very very much man. You have just saved the day. Now it works as it should work. Many many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static ArrayList<Human> sortArrayList(ArrayList<Human> arr){
    ArrayList<Human> result = new ArrayList<Human>();
    Map<Double, Human> map = new HashMap<Double, Human>();
    for (Human human : arr)
        map.put(human.salary, human);
    List<Double> salaries = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (double salary : map.keySet())
        salaries.add(salary);
    Collections.sort(salaries);
    for (int i = 0; i < salaries.size(); i++)
        result.add(map.get(salaries.get(i)));
    return result;
}
```

This is untested but it should work, **assuming `.salary` is a double** *(which it might not be)*

Comment: Probably it works, i cannot check now because it shows some mistakes with your method and i'm too tired to deal more with the code, because i was trying to solve the problem for a few days, i've read so many articles and stuff, but i've learned so many things. Thanks for the answer though, i appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem has already been solved, but regardless here is how I would've thought to do the sort.

```
private static ArrayList<Human> sortArrayList(ArrayList<Human> arr){
    if(arr.size()==0){
        return null;
    }
    else{
         ArrayList<Human> result = new ArrayList<Human>();
        for(Human h : arr){
            result.add(h);
        }
        Human temp;
        for(int i=0; i<result.size()-1; i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<result.size(); j++){
                if(result.get(j).salary < result.get(i).salary){
                    temp = result.get(j);
                    result.remove(j);
                    result.add(i, temp);
                }
            }//end for j
        }//end for i
        return result;
    }//end else
}// end sort
```

Comment: yep i've tried this method and it works, but the condition was to not touch the algorithm and to find the mistake in the code i've posted. Thank you for answering though!

Comment: Ah I see. Fair enough :)